# Action Script 3.0: how can I type other languages in the array or how can I use the other languages in grids

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is my code. This is my word search game ...In word list array ...these are my questions to find in grid in the game...my questions how can I type other languages in the array or how can I use the other languages in grids

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.filters.GlowFilter;


 const puzzleSize:uint = 20;
 const spacing:Number = 24;
 const outlineSize:Number = 20;
 const offsetoint = new Point(162.9,179.7);
 const offsettoint = new Point(300,265);
 const spacingg:Number = 36;
 const letterFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Bamini",18,0x000000,true,false,false,null,null,TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

// words and grid
 var wordList:Array;
 var usedWords:Array;
 var grid:Array;

// game state
 var dragModetring;
 var startPoint,endPointoint;
 var numFound:int;

// sprites
 var gameSpriteprite;
 var outlineSpriteprite;
 var oldOutlineSpriteprite;
 var letterSpritesprite;
 var wordsSpriteprite;



 startWordSearch();

 function startWordSearch() {
**// word list**



wordList = ("Lion,Tiger,Cheetah,Panther".split(",";

// set up the sprites
gameSprite = new Sprite();
addChild(gameSprite);

oldOutlineSprite = new Sprite();
gameSprite.addChild(oldOutlineSprite);

outlineSprite = new Sprite();
gameSprite.addChild(outlineSprite);

letterSprites = new Sprite();
gameSprite.addChild(letterSprites);

wordsSprite = new Sprite();
gameSprite.addChild(wordsSprite);

// array of letters
var letters:Array = placeLetters();

// array of sprites
grid = new Array();
for(var x:int=0;x<puzzleSize;x++) {
grid[x] = new Array();
for(var y:int=0;y<puzzleSize;y++) {

// create new letter field and sprite
var newLetter:TextField = new TextField();
newLetter.defaultTextFormat = letterFormat;
newLetter.x = x*spacing + offset.x;
newLetter.y = y*spacing + offset.y;
newLetter.width = spacing;
newLetter.height = spacing;
newLetter.text = letters[x][y];
newLetter.selectable = false;
var newLetterSpriteprite = new Sprite();
newLetterSprite.addChild(newLetter);
letterSprites.addChild(newLetterSprite);
grid[x][y] = newLetterSprite;

// add event listeners
newLetterSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickLetter);
newLetterSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overLetter);
}
}

// stage listener
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseRelease);

// create word list fields and sprites
for(var i:int=0;i<usedWords.length;i++) {
//var myglow:GlowFilter=new GlowFilter();
//myglow.color = 0x0000FF;
//myglow.blurX=5;
//myglow.blurY=5;
//myglow.strength=200;

var newWord:TextField = new TextField();
newWord.defaultTextFormat = letterFormat;
newWord.x = 700;
newWord.y = i*spacingg+offsett.y;
newWord.width =140;
newWord.height =spacing;
newWord.text = usedWords[i];
//newWord.filters=[myglow];
newWord.selectable = false;

wordsSprite.addChild(newWord);
}

// set game state
dragMode = "none";
numFound = 0;
}

// place the words in a grid of letters
 function placeLetters():Array {

// create empty grid
var letters:Array = new Array();
for(var x:int=0;x<puzzleSize;x++) {
letters[x] = new Array();
for(var y:int=0;y<puzzleSize;y++) {
letters[x][y] = "*";
}
}

// make copy of word list
var wordListCopy:Array = wordList.concat();
usedWords = new Array();

// make 1000 attempts to add words
var repeatTimes:int = 1000;
repeatLoop:while (wordListCopy.length > 0) {
if (repeatTimes-- <= 0) break;

// pick a random word, location and direction
var wordNum:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*wordListCopy.length);
var wordtring = wordListCopy[wordNum].toUpperCase();
x = Math.floor(Math.random()*puzzleSize);
y = Math.floor(Math.random()*puzzleSize);
var dx:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)-1;
var dy:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)-1;
if ((dx == 0) && (dy == 0)) continue repeatLoop;

// check each spot in grid to see if word fits
letterLoop:for (var j:int=0;j<word.length;j++) {
if ((x+dx*j < 0) || (y+dy*j < 0) || (x+dx*j >= puzzleSize) || (y+dy*j >= puzzleSize)) continue repeatLoop;
var thisLettertring = letters[x+dx*j][y+dy*j];
if ((thisLetter != "*" && (thisLetter != word.charAt(j))) continue repeatLoop;
}

// insert word into grid
insertLoop:for (j=0;j<word.length;j++) {
letters[x+dx*j][y+dy*j] = word.charAt(j);
}

// remove word from list
wordListCopy.splice(wordNum,1);
usedWords.push(word);
}

// fill rest of grid with random letters
for(x=0;x<puzzleSize;x++) {
for(y=0;y<puzzleSize;y++) {
if (letters[x][y] == "*" {
letters[x][y] = String.fromCharCode(65+Math.floor(Math.random()*26));
}
}
}

return letters;
}

// player clicks down on a letter to start
 function clickLetter(event:MouseEvent) {
var lettertring = event.currentTarget.getChildAt(0).text;
startPoint = findGridPoint(event.currentTarget);
dragMode = "drag";
}

// player dragging over letters
 function overLetter(event:MouseEvent) {
if (dragMode == "drag" {
endPoint = findGridPoint(event.currentTarget);

// if valid range, show outline
outlineSprite.graphics.clear();
if (isValidRange(startPoint,endPoint)) {
drawOutline(outlineSprite,startPoint,endPoint,0x66CCFF);
}
}
}

// mouse released
 function mouseRelease(event:MouseEvent) {
if (dragMode == "drag" {
dragMode = "none";
outlineSprite.graphics.clear();

// get word and check it
if (isValidRange(startPoint,endPoint)) {
var word = getSelectedWord();
checkWord(word);
}
}
}

// when a letter is clicked, find and return the x and y location
 function findGridPoint(letterSpritebject)oint {

// loop through all sprites and find this one
for(var x:int=0;x<puzzleSize;x++) {
for(var y:int=0;y<puzzleSize;y++) {
if (grid[x][y] == letterSprite) {
return new Point(x,y);
}
}
}
return null;
}

// determine if range is in the same row, column, or a 45 degree diagonal
 function isValidRange(p1,p2oint):Boolean {
if (p1.x == p2.x) return true;
if (p1.y == p2.y) return true;
if (Math.abs(p2.x-p1.x) == Math.abs(p2.y-p1.y)) return true;
return false;
}

// draw a thick line from one location to another
 function drawOutline(sprite,p1,p2oint,c:Number) {
var offoint = new Point(offset.x+spacing/2, offset.y+spacing/2);
s.graphics.lineStyle(outlineSize,c);
s.graphics.moveTo(p1.x*spacing+off.x ,p1.y*spacing+off.y);
s.graphics.lineTo(p2.x*spacing+off.x ,p2.y*spacing+off.y);
}

// find selected letters based on start and end points
 function getSelectedWord()tring {

// determine dx and dy of selection, and word length
var dx = endPoint.x-startPoint.x;
var dy = endPoint.y-startPoint.y;
var wordLength:Number = Math.max(Math.abs(dx),Math.abs(dy))+1;

// get each character of selection
var wordtring = "";
for(var i:int=0;i<wordLength;i++) {
var x = startPoint.x;
if (dx < 0) x -= i;
if (dx > 0) x += i;
var y = startPoint.y;
if (dy < 0) y -= i;
if (dy > 0) y += i;
word += grid[x][y].getChildAt(0).text;
}
return word;
}

// check word against word list
 function checkWord(wordtring) {

// loop through words
for(var i:int=0;i<usedWords.length;i++) {

// compare word
if (word == usedWords[i].toUpperCase()) {
foundWord(word);
}

// compare word reversed
var reverseWordtring = word.split("".reverse().join("";
if (reverseWord == usedWords[i].toUpperCase()) {
foundWord(reverseWord);
}
}
}

// word found, remove from list, make outline permanent
       function foundWord(wordtring) {

// draw outline in permanent sprite
drawOutline(oldOutlineSprite,startPoint,endPoint,0xE01212);

// find text field and set it to gray
for(var i:int=0;i<wordsSprite.numChildren;i++) {
if (TextField(wordsSprite.getChildAt).text.toUpperCase() == word) {
TextField(wordsSprite.getChildAt).textColor = 0xFF0000;
}
}

// see if all have been found
numFound++;
if (numFound ==usedWords.length) {
endGame();

}
}

 function endGame() {
gotoAndStop("gameover";
cleanUp();
Timee.stop();

}

 function cleanUp() {
removeChild(gameSprite);
gameSprite = null;
grid = null;
vv=null;
}
```

Comment: The question what you need is "change the language from English to others (Japanese, French, German and so on)"?
How about set other language characters to wordList array.
Did you get any errors? or didn't show characters?

Comment: i want to add tamil language letters to my whole grid ..........how can i add that into my grid ....pls help ...

Comment: i just changed the font here :                                                                   const letterFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Bamini",18,0x000000,true,false,false,null,null,TextFormatAlign.CENTER);     Arial to Bamini   bamini is a tamil font which i need

Comment: i trying to do a game like this http://tamilwordgame.appspot.com/     if you know means pls help ..thanks in advance

Comment: However I'm using flex, it shows Tamil characters without special settings. http://wonderfl.net/c/s5AC

Comment: i am not using flex ...am only using flash ...try above code it shows special characters .......pls help thanks in advance